# PHP regex Word Boundaries doesnt match end of string

Tags: php, regex

i want to find an exact word has been a string. but if its end of the string, word boundaries failing. i thought because of special turkish chars but second code works expected. where is my mistake?

this code returns 0

```
$row = "TEDARİKÇİ,MÜŞTERİ";
var_dump( preg_match('#\bMÜŞTERİ\b#iu', $row));
```

but this one returns 1

```
$row = "TEDARİKÇİ,MÜŞTERİ";
var_dump( preg_match('#\bMÜŞTERİ$#iu', $row));
```

Comment: The two works well for me and return `1` as expected. https://eval.in/354283

Comment: There's no problem with `\b` .See here https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/9

Comment: A word boundary matches position before the first word character in the string, after the last word character in the string, and between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character, so both examples should work fine.

Comment: i think reason is version differences. my local server has an old php 5.2 but  actual server has newer version and its worked normally. thanks for efforts.

Comment: additional info: php regex processor thinks İ (big letter I with dot - turkish special chars) is a word boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I though both regex should work but I got same problem as you in regex101. So, in order to fix this you can change your regex to:

```
$row = "TEDARİKÇİ,MÜŞTERİ";
var_dump( preg_match('#\bMÜŞTERİ(\b|$)#iu', $row));
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/nK2tO5/2)**